# Why does this not unset the two most significant bits?

Tags: c#, serial-port, bit-manipulation

I have a feeling this has to do with the way `BitConverter.ToUInt16` wiorks, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this is giving me funky data.

I need to ignore the first two bits coming in on the port and convert the remaining bits to a 16-bit unsigned integer.

I have tried reversing the array, reversing my mask, doing both, different conversions, and all sorts of weird things.

The two bytes that come in are with the first one being the most significant. The first two bits in the first byte need to be unset.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
int count = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Console.WriteLine("0: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(buffer));

ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);

Console.WriteLine("1: {0}", value);

value = (ushort)(value & 0x3FFF);

Console.WriteLine("2: {0}", value);
```

Here is some sample data when using BitConverter.ToUInt16 and then ANDing with the `0x3FFF` mask.

```
0: 80-00
1: 128
2: 128 <-- this should be 0

0: 80-00
1: 128
2: 128 <-- should be 0

0: 01-00
1: 1
2: 1 <-- should be 1, as it is

0: 80-00
1: 128
2: 128 <-- should be 0

0: 80-00
1: 128
2: 128 <-- should be 0
```

Reversing the array gives me data like this:

```
0: 00-01
1: 256
2: 256 <-- should be 1

0: 01-80
1: 32769
2: 1 <- not sure what this should be, probably 1 though
```

Comment: What do you end up with in `value`?

Comment: @DWright I added it to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so people have the full code for the serial port reading and converting of a 14-bit unsigned big endian integer.

```
private static void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;
    if (port.BytesToRead < sizeof(ushort))
    {
        return;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
    int count = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    ushort value = (ushort)(((buffer[0] << 8) | buffer[1]) & 0x3FFF);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The two bytes that come in are with the first one being the most significant.

That's the problem. `BitConverter.ToUInt16` treats the first byte as the least significant, because that's how your system works. See `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

> I have tried reversing the array,

That should work. Alternatively, combine the two bytes manually, without using `BitConverter`.

Comment: I've tried manually combining the two bytes by taking the first and left shifting by 8 and then ORing it against the second and then applying the mask. Is the mask correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct to me. `0x3FFF` has bits 0-13 set, and bit 14 and 15 cleared, so and-ing with that clears the top 2 bits.

Comment: So what I have currently is just doing what I explained in my first comment to your answer. I receive some results as correct and others not so correct. Specifically when the device transmits `1`, I receive `80-01` and when the device transmits what I think is `2`, I receive `02-00`. Any thoughts on why my masking isn't calculating the value appropriately?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Your question suggests `2` gets sent as `00 02` (or `80 02` or such). If it doesn't, you first need to figure out the rules your device uses for sending data.

Comment: The raw data I get sent for a `1` is sometimes `01 00` and also sometimes `80 01`. The first two bits of either 16-bit unsigned integers needs to be ignored, so the values should be the same since the most significant byte is first in the series. So, the most significant bits of the most significant byte need to be ignored. `10 1C = 28 (dec)` is the example provided in my documentation.

Comment: I found that there's a problem with the device not transmitting the whole data, so it gets funky when I tell it to interpret two bytes where it only received half. Boy I love serial communication. Your solution works.